# Filling GridView on some Button Click in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on some project which is in classic ASP.NET, but I need to migarate that into MVC

Right Now I am having a page with one button and gridview which get fill on clicking the button. Gridview has the functionality like EDIT, DELETE, Paging, OnRowCommand Event.

How should I perform this page through MVC. I know gridview can't be used in MVC, so what's the alternative of that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you reviewed the [NerdDinner Tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) yet?  It would be really helpful if you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the perfect answer for me

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/06/Code-based-ASPNET-MVC-GridView.aspx

It works good for me clearlly understandable for me, I would say @amarsuperstar example also looks fine but not looks for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a jQuery Grid plugin, [like this one.](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)  I assume you have already figured out how to populate your view with data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Telerik MVC Grid Control. They are free and open source, and I am using these at the moment and don't have a bad thing to say about them!

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax

Comment: I wouldn't say they are exactly "free as in speech."  They are GPLv2; not even a library exemption.